# Do I need a PTR (rDNS [Reverse DNS]) record if using an SMTP mail relay (Mailgun, Mailjet, Send Grid, etc.)?

Tags: domain-name-system, smtp, email-server, reverse-dns, ptr-record

My cloud hosting provider wants to charge for setting up a PTR record, which I'm not up for.

As I use Mailjet as an SMTP relay server, do I even need to have it setup? Or will all my emails reverse to *their* SMTP server?

Comment: The short answer is no.  If you are submitting mail to an external mailserver for delivery, it will be their `PTR` record that needs to be set correctly.  You still need to set up other things like `spf` records, but don't need a `PTR`.

Comment: @anx - It's automated, but in order to setup a DNS Zone (a pre-requisite for the PTR), there's additional fees involved.

Comment: You're right charging for setting PTR record is a tad off, it's a basic (free) feature offered by most providers OVH, Vultur, etc - it's literally a single record set on a nameservers.

As tater mentioned, it's not needed since you're using a third party; thus emails will originate from there mail servers.